# Pick the file with the shortest name

Tags: python

I want to find the .txt file with the shortest name inside a folder.

```
import glob
import os

inpDir = "C:/Users/ft/Desktop/Folder"

os.chdir(inpDir)

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    l = len(file)
```

For the moment I found the length of the str of the name, how can I return the shortest name?
Thanks

Comment: just take the minimum of the variable l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the shortest file just compare to the current shortest:

```py
chosen_file = ""

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    if chosen_file == "" or len(file) < len(chosen_file):
        chosen_file = file

print(f"{chosen_file} is the shortest file")
```

Once you've finished the loop, the `chosen_file` str is guaranteed to be the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner to put it in a function and calling it:

```py
import glob
import os

def shortest_file_name(inpDir: str, extension: str) -> str:
    os.chdir(inpDir)
    shortest, l = '', 0b100000000
    for file in glob.glob(extension):
        if len(file) < l:
            l = len(file)
            shortest = file
    return shortest

inpDir = "C:/Users/ft/Desktop/Folder"
min_file_name = shortest_file_name(inpDir, "*.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `glob` module to get a list of files, and then utilize `min(..., key=...)` to find the shortest string (see `help(min)`):

```
min(glob.glob('*.txt'), key=len)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
min = 1000

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    if len(file) < min:
        min = len(file)
        name = file
```

Comment: Don't overwrite/shadow builtin function `min`. what if the min is > 1000 characters?